# Prepended field is not captured while form submission. - jquery / php

Tags: php, jquery, database, forms

I prepend

```
$('.VHere').prepend('<input type="checkbox" value="test1" id="testid">');
```

And write into the DB. When posting via form, the  does not capture #testid.    It capture every other field in the form except for this.  Also if the page is reloaded this particular field is captured.

Any idea why.

Comment: i think, prepending is working not fast enough, after reload the html is prepended then it will see it.. just guess, can also be wrong what i am saying, sorry for that

Comment: You're missing all the code necessary to help you - e.g. what is `.VHere` - don't answer with a comment - edit the question adding the html for your form, and the js you're using (are you submitting it via ajax?). Note that checkboxes aren't included in post data unless they are checked.

Comment: You need to also add `name="testid"` to that element if you are using a form to do the submission. If you're using jQuery to do the submission, then post your jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see more code, but there is no `name` associated with this `input`, which may be why the content is not being added to the DB.

I would think it would be

```
$('.VHere').
   prepend('<input type="checkbox" name="testid" value="test1" id="testid">');
```

where `testid` populates the field

Comment: echo $var does not appear too.

Comment: and where is `$var` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

may be this works?

```
$('.VHere').prepend('<input type="checkbox" name="testid" checked="checked" value="test1" id="testid">');
```

because unchecked box cannot be submitted with post as AD7six says and `name` is of course important to post and catch back..